# Error uploading a PDF file using AJAX, but not with other formats (JPG, DOC, ZIP, etc.)

Tags: jquery, ajax, file, upload

I created a form to upload some data and a file. It works perfectly except for PDF files. Also, if I create a .zip file with a .pdf within it doesn't work either.

I can see that this is a known error but I don't know how to solve it. Can anybody help me?

```html
<form name="form" id="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label>Nombre</label>
  <input type="text" name="nombre" required>
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file" value="ADJUNTAR ARCHIVO" />
  <button class="btn-envio" data-status="idle" value="Enviar">Enviar</button>
  <div class="statusMsg"></div>
</form>
```

```js
$("#form").on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = $('form')[0];
  var valores = new FormData(form);
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'validar.php',
    data: valores,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    beforeSend: function() {
      $('#form').css("opacity", ".5");
    },
    success: function(response) {},
    error: function(e) {}
  });
});
```

Comment: What's the error? Check your PHP code to ensure it's not configured to only accept files with certain MIME types.

Comment: If I don't use AJAX I have no problem to upload pdf files. The error is when I use the function move_upload( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $filePath), $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] is empty so the function returns false